# <tbody> element is stuffed into first column of a table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to hide/reveal table rows based on checking a checkbox.

Here it is http://dbdev2.pharmacy.arizona.edu/wideproblem.html

How do I get the hidden row to properly display at the width of the table? I've even tried setting it as a css attribute for that row, and it doesn't work.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>The Case of the Squished Row</title>
<style>
table {
    border: 1px solid black;
     width: 600px;
    }
tr {border:1px solid black;}
tr.anote {width:600px;}
th {
    border:1px solid black;
    width:50%;
    }
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 25%;
    }

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowRow(msg){
        var thecheck = document.getElementById("showcheck");
        var thebox= document.getElementById("showbox");
        var thenote= document.getElementById("shownote");
        if (thecheck.checked){
            thebox.innerHTML=msg;
            thebox.style.color='red';
            thenote.style.display='block';
            }
        else {
            thebox.innerHTML='This is a checkbox';
            thebox.style.color='black';
            thenote.style.display='none';
            }

        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>The Case of the Squished Row</h1>
<br><br>
<h2> using display:none CSS property</h2>
<table>
<tbody id="topline">
<tr><th id="showbox">This is a checkbox</th>
<td><input type="checkbox" id="showcheck" onclick="ShowRow('Note is DISPLAY:BLOCK')"></td>
<td>this is filler</td></tr>
</tbody>
<tbody id="shownote" style="display:none">
<tr class="anote"><th>This is a note</th><td>Hey! The box is checked!</td><td>this is filler</td></tr>
</tbody>
<tbody id="botline">
<tr><th>Big Filler</th><td>Little filler</td><td>this is filler</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use "table-row-group", not "block" as the value of the "display" property when showing the table row group (the `<tbody>`).

Comment: In old versions of Internet Explorer, well, good luck. I don't have a browser running to try it.

Comment: IE8 and later should understand `display: table-row-group`, but if setting the display style in JS, older versions may be able to figure out on their own what to do if you set it to the empty string instead of an explicit value.